# How to push into an array using nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying to push the file into the array named `FileName` however when I try to `console.log(FileName)` all I get is the empty array! Any input would be greatly appreciated!

```
const fs = require("fs");
const mm = require("music-metadata");
const dataFolder = "../../Songs";
const util = require("util");
//requiring path and fs modules
const path = require("path");
let FileName = [];
fs.readdir(dataFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(e => {
    return mm.parseFile(`../../Songs/${e}`).then(metadata => {
      // console.log(`../..Songs/${e}`);
      FileName.push(e);
      // console.log(
      //   util.inspect(metadata.common.title, {
      //     showHidden: false,
      //     depth: null
      //   })
      // );
    });
  });
});
console.log(FileName);
// mm.parseFile(
//   "/Users/nathangriffith/Desktop/dashboard/Songs/04 Smoke and Mirrors.m4a"
// )
//   .then(metadata => {
//     console.log(
//       metadata.native.iTunes[0].value
//     );
//   })
//   .catch(err => {
//     console.error(err.message);
//   });
```

Comment: Wait, do you just need the value from the `readdir` call in the `FileName` array?  That's what you're doing when you call `FileName.push(e);`.  However, I'll post an answer assuming that you need `metdata` in the `FileName` array...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you need `metadata` in your `FileName` array:

```js
const files = readdirSync(dataFolder); // Now files is an array of file names

Promise
  .all(files.map(file => mm.parseFile(`../../Songs/${file}`)
  .then(metadataArr => {
    console.log(metadataArr); // This should be your parsed metdatas
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running an async function and expecting it to complete before the next line (console.log) runs. The log runs *during* the runtime of readdir, and therefore prints the value of FileName as it is *before* readdir changes it.

You can either change the program to use await/async correctly, or implement readdirSync instead.